# The name <js_variable> does not exist in the current context

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I have the following Model set up where there is a `List<string>` that I am trying to add a value to:

```
public class NewShipmentModel
{
    ...
    public List<string> units_selected { get; set; }

    public NewShipmentModel()
    {
        units_selected = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

In my View, I have an EventListener set on a checkbox where I am trying to take the value of that checkbox and either add or remove it from that list using Javascript and Razor:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < unitCheckboxes.length; i++) {
        unitCheckboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function () {

            var addition = 0;
            var unit_serial = this.value;
            var curr_val = (this.name == "Base") ? parseInt($("#total-bases-selected").text()) : parseInt($("#total-clients-selected").text());

            if (this.checked) {
                addition = 1;
                @Model.units_selected.Add(unit_serial);  // ERROR HERE
            }  else {
                addition = -1;
                @Model.units_selected.Remove(unit_serial);  // ERROR HERE
            }

            curr_val = curr_val + addition;

            if (this.name == "Base")
                $("#total-bases-selected").text(curr_val);
            else
                $("#total-clients-selected").text(curr_val);

        }, false);
    }
```

However, actually trying to add or remove the value fails where I have marked `ERROR HERE` in the comments.  The issue is that it cannot access `unit_serial` as it seems to be out of scope to Razor:

```
The name unit_serial does not exist in the current context
```

How do I properly access the variable?  Is this possible?

---

**EDIT**:  Note that data is currently passed back to the controller via a `submit` button and HTTP POST.  I'm not sure how to populate this list and/or inject it with the data in the rest of my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that you're confusing server and client code. Razor part is always executes on server. Javascript - on the client. Therefore you can't just do

```
//note that unit_serial doesn't exist when you're calling Add method because it
//executes during razor view generation on server.
//all javascript code executes after the client receive generated view.
@Model.units_selected.Add(unit_serial);
```

in the middle of javascript code, because it doesn't make sense. When change event handler fires on checkboxes: you would send this to server for updating.

For making it work consider to create one more mvc action and use ajax for passing data to server.